# Simple POST with Web Api .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, post, .net-core

I can't produce my code despite the different questions and answers found on stackoverflow.

Here is my problem, I want to receive the `Username` and `Password` of the client to perform the verification (the equality is only for the example).

However the `LoginPost` variable is all the time `null`.
Furthermore I have difficulty understanding the best way to send the client an http code and json at the same time.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using web.Models;

namespace web.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<LoginPost> LoginPost([FromBody] LoginPost loginPost)
        {
            // (1) FAIL, loginPost variable is null

            if (loginPost.Username == loginPost.Password)
            {
                return loginPost;
            }


            // (2) How to add a message like "User/Password fails"

            return Unauthorized(); 
        }

    }
}
```

Note the annotations (1) and (2) in the code.

Here's the `jQuery code`

```
$.ajax({
        url: '../api/Login',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json, charset=utf-8",
        data: {
            Username: username,
            Password: password
        },
        statusCode: {
            200: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
            401: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
            500: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
});
```

and `LoginPost.cs` class:

```
public class LoginPost
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So what does the above code do? Is there an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: @DavidG I explained it, I don't understand the interest of your message

Comment: @DavidG I may repeat myself but the `[FromBody] LoginPost` data is all the time `null`. I can't receive data by POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login controller is working fine, I tested it with Postman. The problem lies with the ajax call: it does not send the data as the body of the `POST` request but as URL query parameters (i.e. `Username=username&Password=password`).

To send the data in the body of the `POST` request you need to send the data as `json` string:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    "Username": "username",
    "Password": "password"
}),
```

Comment: Well! But how to avoid the `JSON.stringify` function? I need to change `[FromBody]` to another ?
With the old .NET version, it use `[FromUri]` but it doesn't exist here

Comment: The simplest solution would be to remove the `[FromBody]` attribute and remove `contentType` from the ajax call. Then the data will be sent as `form data` and it just works.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't seem to want to use `json`, post the data as a form.

Remove 
`contentType: "application/json, charset=utf-8",`
from your ajax call.

`'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` is the default so the data will be sent as a form.
Also remove `[FromBody]` Attribute and it should work

Answer (score 1):

For (2) question, you can return status code :

```
return StatusCode(401, "User/Password fails");
```